# "Deutsch" oder "Deutschen"

Tags: word-usage

Welche Variante ist jeweils richtig und wie lautet die Regel?

> Im Deutschen schreibt man Nomen groß.
>
> Im Deutsch schreibt man Nomen groß.

und

> Das verhält sich so wie im Deutschen.
>
> Das verhält sich so wie im Deutsch.

Oder sind beide Varianten richtig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es heißt *im Deutschen*, *im Englischen*, *im Serbokroatischen* usw. Warum? Weil **im** den Dativ verlangt. Das Nomen ist hierbei *das Deutsche*, *das Englische*, *das Serbokroatische*, das eigentliche Wort für die Sprache.

Du kannst alternativ *auf Deutsch*, *auf Englisch*, *auf Serbokroatisch* schreiben. Weil **auf** in der Bedeutung "in der Sprache" den Akkusativ verlangt. Es handelt sich aber hier zusätzlich noch um ein anderes Nomen, welches vom Adjektiv *deutsch*, *englisch*, *serbokroatisch* abgeleitet ist. Solche Nomen werden anders flektiert.

Comment: Die Antwort trifft zu, aber nicht die Begründung. Wir haben zwei Wörter, nämlich einerseits das Substantiv «das Deutsch», und andererseits das Adjektiv «das Deutsche» (gross geschrieben da «substantiviert», aber trotzdem mit Adjektivdeklination. Die Verteilung der beiden Wörter ist kompliziert. Das Substantiv wird etwa dann gebraucht, wenn es um die Sprache einer bestimmten Person geht. Dann sagt man «sein Deutsch ist vorzüglich» oder «in seinem vorzüglichen Deutsch». Im gegebenen Fall würde man wohl eher das Adjektiv verwenden.