# Why do we say" im Deutschen" instead of "in Deutsch"?

Tags: adjective-ending

When we want to say *in german*, I noticed some say *im Deutschen* instead of *in Deutsch*. I'm confused as to why *Deutschen* has an *n* at the end and why it is a name and not an adjective.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Deutsch" oder "Deutschen"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36064/deutsch-oder-deutschen)

Comment: In the linked question, the accepted answer misses the point (as the comment shows). See also: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/1749/35111

Comment: @DavidVogt, technically that is not a reason for this question not to be marked as a duplicate. The preferred way would be to place a bounty on the existing question to encourage better answers.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate as this question is in English and the other in German.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich, *that* is of course a reason.

Answer (score 4):

*in German = auf deutsch* 1:1

*im Deutschen* is something like *in der deutschen Sprache*

verwandt: ins Deutsche (übersetzen)

Comment: Colloquially we also can say "in Deutsch", but never "im Deutsch".

Answer (score 0):

"Das Deutsche" is just a noun, and it means the same as "die deutsche Sprache". It's not very common any more except in some idioms, like in "ins Deutsche übersetzt"

> Das Deutsche ist die Sprache Luthers und Goethes. (Nominativ)
>
> Sie war des Deutschen mächtig (Genitiv) (i.e. sie war der deutschen Sprache mächtig i.e. sie sprach deutsch)
>
> Im Deutschen sagen wir "Sommerurlaub". (Dativ)
>
> Ich habe das Deutsche als Kind in Frankreich in der Schule gelernt. (Akkusativ)
>
> Schlegel und Tieck haben Shakespeare ins Deutsche übersetzt. (Akkusativ)